# Pandas - Create Multiindex columns during rename

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I'm trying to find a simple way to rename a flat column index to a hierarchical multindex column set. I've come across one way, but it seems a bit kludgy - is there a better way to do this in Pandas?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

flat_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(4, 4)), columns=list('ACBD'))

print flat_df

#      A   C   B   D
#  0  27  67  35  36
#  1  80  42  93  20
#  2  64   9  18  83
#  3  85  69  60  84


nested_columns = {'A': ('One', 'a'),
                  'C': ('One', 'c'),
                  'B': ('Two', 'b'),
                  'D': ('Two', 'd'),
                  }

tuples = sorted(nested_columns.values(), key=lambda x: x[1]) # Sort by second value
nested_df = flat_df.sort_index(axis=1) # Sort dataframe by column name
nested_df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
nested_df = nested_df.sort_index(level=0, axis=1) # Sort to group first level

print nested_df

#    One     Two    
#      a   c   b   d
#  0  27  67  35  36
#  1  80  42  93  20
#  2  64   9  18  83
#  3  85  69  60  84
```

It seems a bit fragile to sort both the hierarchical column specification as well as the dataframe and assume they'll line up. Also sorting three times seems ridiculous. The alternative I'd prefer would be something like `nested_df = flat_df.rename(columns=nested_columns)`, but it seems that `rename` isn't able to go from flat column indexing to multiindex columns. Am I missing something?

Edit: Realized this would break if the tuples sorted by second value don't sort the same as the flat column names. *Definitely* the wrong approach.

Edit2: 
In response to @wen's answer:

```
nested_df = flat_df.rename(columns=nested_columns)
print nested_df
#    (One, a)  (One, c)  (Two, b)  (Two, d)
# 0        18         0        51        48
# 1        69        68        78        24
# 2         2        20        99        46
# 3         1        80        11        11
```

Edit3:

Based on @ScottBoston's answer, here's a working solution that accounts for flat columns not mentioned in the nested columns:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

flat_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(4, 5)), columns=list('ACBDE'))

print flat_df
#     A   C   B   D   E
# 0  27  68   4  98  16
# 1   0   9   9  72  68
# 2  91  17  19  54  99
# 3  14  96  54  79  28

nested_columns = {'A': ('One', 'e'),
                  'C': ('One', 'h'),
                  'B': ('Two', 'f'),
                  'D': ('Two', 'g'),
                  }

nested_df = flat_df.rename(columns=nested_columns)
nested_df.columns = [c if isinstance(c, tuple) else ('', c) for c in nested_df.columns]
nested_df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(nested_df.columns)

print nested_df
#   One     Two        
#     e   h   f   g   E
# 0  27  68   4  98  16
# 1   0   9   9  72  68
# 2  91  17  19  54  99
# 3  14  96  54  79  28
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.rename(columns = nested_columns).columns)
df
```

Output:

```
  One     Two    
    a   c   b   d
0  27  67  35  36
1  80  42  93  20
2  64   9  18  83
3  85  69  60  84
```

Comment: That's very close to being the perfect answer! The only problem arises from not all columns being part of a  `tuple` from `df.rename`, but I can always preprocess the columns after the rename to ensure they're all tuples.

Comment: For example, if, keeping everything else the same in the original problem, I used `flat_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(4, 5)), columns=list('ACBDE'))`, this solution breaks.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, `rename`

```
flat_df.rename(columns=nested_columns)
Out[224]: 
  One     Two    
    a   c   b   d
0  36  19  53  46
1  17  85  63  36
2  40  80  75  86
3  31  83  75  16
```

Updated

```
flat_df.columns.map(nested_columns.get)
Out[15]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[['One', 'Two'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 1, 3]])
```

Comment: Hm... I am getting tuples as headers instead of pd.MultiIndex when I try this.

Comment: @ScottBoston umm what version you have for pandas

Comment: pd.__version__ "0.23.3"

Comment: @ScottBoston I have pd.__version__
Out[7]: '0.22.0'

Comment: @Wen First thing I tried. Sadly, didn't work with Pandas 0.23.3

Comment: @NickSweet wired behavior ...ummm

Comment: @ScottBoston maybe my pandas is broken ?

Comment: Probably need to look through the "What's New" docs for pandas to see if that was intended to be broken/fix.  Otherwise, might submit a bug report on it.

Comment: The updated solution works, but suffers from the same issue as @ScottBoston's solution (existence of a non-hierarchical index alongside the others)